# Reinstall app as a New user when it is detecting that we have already used this app before

Tags: android

Suppose I have an app that requires Registration from my number. If i reinstalled the app after clearing all previously stored data, how it is detecting that i have already used this app before? How can I register as a new user using a new number?

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, in the `<application ...` tag, add the following attribute:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

By default it's true. And after you add this, run your app, and clear data. That's it.